# "Real install" of core-linux (TinyCore)

Tags: linux, tinycore

I want to setup the core (just CLI) version of the tinycorelinux-Project on a hard disk with a real root file system, not the emulated variant with the need of manually saving the progress. Has anybody done this before?

Comment: Found it out myself some time ago: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1000688.html